# findLibrary returned null happened sometimes

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xxxx(this is the name of the library, i just made it xxx): findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
```

This crash happens **sometimes** not always. And it usually happens on the **Android 2.3** devices. It's confusing that why it does not always happen and only sometimes. I couldn't find any clues about this crash.
Is it relative to some API that is not supported on the Android 2.3?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This happens when your JAVA could not find its reference method that should be there in Native means in C/C++
means java call the JNI and when it can`t get the refrence method it cause **UnsatisfiedLinkError**

Comment: Thank you very much! But why it happens sometimes and usually happens in Android 2.3?

Comment: Does it ever succeed on the 2.3 device?

Comment: Yes. It does not happen on my Android 2.3 device. But others are able to reproduce this issue with Android 2.3 sometimes.

Comment: Is it possible that the library is not on their devices?

Comment: It's not a system library. It's a library that included in the APK.

Comment: I wonder if you didn't compile the c library for all architectures... just a thought. Can you tell us what architectures your library was built for?

Comment: You might need to compile for the other architectures - perhaps you can find out what phones this error is occuring on.

Comment: @krsteeve compile one library .so file for one architectures? This crash usually happens with android 2.3 version, but not for particular type of phones.

Comment: Android can run on x86 and mips - these phones are rare but should be considered

Comment: @krsteeve I checked the information of the devices that this bug happened with. There are some devices that is ARM among them. It seems that it's not relative to the x86 and mips.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Generally when this happens there is a bit more data available in logcat. Likely a symbol(s) that aren't available on the particular device. For example, Amazon shipped some devices with a couple missing standard C exports.