# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null - happens RARELY

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

*** Please don't answer about basic JNI and shared library tutorial. It happens RARELY!!**

I have the similar issue with [findLibrary returned null happened sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479710).
But it happens rarely.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xxxx: findLibrary returned null

I've never seen it on my devices - 12 devices with various android versions.
**It shows up only on crash report.**

I think it could be a fault of package installer on Android because I've even seen some crash reports saying FileNotFoundException on a xml file contained in apk obviously!

But I'm not sure.
Is there anyone who have correct answer?

Comment: The errors are also seen on crash report. It could be related with memory issues?     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1935]: 1299 missing essential tables

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more information on the devices where your app is facing this issue ? device model/Android version ? Which version of the NDK are you using ?

The issue here is the `Cannot load library: link_image[1935]: 1299 missing essential tables`.
It means that Bionic linker can't load either your library or one of its dependencies, because it's missing the *.strtab* or the *.symtab* section.

You can inspect the depencies and symbols of your libs by using *readelf* or my android app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app&hl=en

Maybe one of the dependencies listed (found in the *DT_NEEDED* part of your library) isn't available on the target system or has been stripped from its symbols. It may happen if you're directly using system libraries that aren't part of the NDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1) I'm using NDK-r9b, 2) various device model and android version. I think it is not related specific model or versions. because it occurs even on the device I've already tested that it's okey. The errors occurs so rarely compared with the number of opens.(0.04%) I think it could related of the resource of the deivce because devices that it occurs multiple times are low-end devices mostly.(Penta WS707C, alps i-mobile IQ3, samsung GT-S7262, LG-E450, HTC VLE_U ). May I ignore it?

Comment: It's possible that this comes from Package Installer failures on these devices because of lack of memory/space. But it's not 100% sure... If you're concerned about this, you can still catch this UnsatisfiedLinkError exception, and tell the user to reinstall the app because there has been an issue with their system.